# matlab multiple dimensional indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

Consider the array

```
 Arr = [a; b; c; d],
```

where a/b/c/d are all arrays of size n.

And I have either an array like

```
index = [1 3 4 2 3 1...]
```

or

```
[
[1 0 0 0 0 1 ....]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 ....]
[0 1 0 0 1 0 ....]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 ....]
]
```

And I want to get out of this

```
[a; c; d; b; c; a ...]
```

How would I use indexing (either logical or otherwise) to do this.

I would like something like
    Arr(index)

but that obviously doesn't do what I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one:

`[Arr(index,:)]`

For the second one:

```
[index,~,~] = find(index);
[Arr(index,:)]
```

Comment: Huh, nice, this works. I must have made a mistake before when I tried this.